# Python: Function simplifying the input instead of passing string

Tags: python, string, function

I need to enter a complex string for handling (UTC time code) and breaking down as part of an assignment. I have started the function like this as required:

```
def convertWmiDateTime(wmiDateTime):
```

But when I enter this:

```
convertWmiDateTime(20061122185433.000000+600)
```

The variable wmiDateTime stores **2.0061122186e+13**

If I use raw_input the value **20061122185433.000000+600** will be stored correctly in wmiDateTime, but not when its called as intended above.

Is there a way to preserve what was typed into the input? A way to stop Pythong calculating and simplifying the number? vb. net would be something like **(wmiDateTime As String)** is there anything like that for Python?

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Using quotation marks around the UTC code works great. Not sure if that's what the assessors want but I cant see any other way so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function requires a string as its input parameter. You can't call it with a number (as you're doing).

`raw_input()` returns a string, so the equivalent would be to call

```
convertWmiDateTime("20061122185433.000000+600")
```

Your version treats the time code as a floating point number which a) doesn't have the required precision to preserve all the digits and b) will get the timezone info (`+600`) added, which leads to wrong results as well.

Comment: I think he/she is looking for a way of creating a string representation of a number which becomes simplified i.e something like `"{0}".format(20061122185433.000000+600)` which doesn't work but gives a sense of what he/she is trying to achieve.